# A question about adding a click event to a dynamically added right-click menu

Tags: vb.net

I want to add click events to the dynamically added right-click menu.The mybutton is a dynamical added button. my codes are as follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim tsm As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem("change icon")
    AddHandler tsm.Click, AddressOf mybutton_changeicon

    mybutton_cms.Items.Add(tsm)
    sender.ContextMenuStrip = mybutton_cms
 End Sub


  Private Sub mybutton_changeicon(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
 System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
      changeIcon.changeicon(sender, e)

  End Sub

 Module changeIcon

  Function changeicon(ByRef Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
  System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs, Optional ByVal Offset As Integer = 10) 
 As Boolean
      Dim openfiledialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
      Dim imagepath As String
      If openfiledialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        imagepath = openfiledialog1.FileName
        Sender.Image = Image.FromFile(imagepath)

    End If

   End Function
End Module
```

when I run it , there is a problem that:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs?
what's wrong with my code?

Comment: In your `mybutton_changeicon` handler, you have declared `e As MouseEventArgs` instead of `e As EventArgs`. Turn Option Strict On to discover another problem.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using `AddHandler` because that `Add` method you're using is overloaded and allows you to provide a `Click` handler there.  As for the issue, how about you show us the `mybutton_changeicon` method, which is where the issue almost certainly is?

Comment: I have added the code of  `mybutton_changeicon`method